# Access superclass static variable in subclass

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a superclass `Test` with a static variable `a` and I've also created a subclass `Test1` from which I am able to access superclass static variable.

Is this a valid way to do so? Any explanation is highly appreciated.

```
public class Test {

    public static String a = "";

    Test() {
        a += "testadd";
    }
}

public class Test1 extends Test {

    public Test1() {
        a += "test1add";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Test1 test1 = new Test1();
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what confuses you exactly?

Comment: @AlexErohin, static variable belongs to a class and in my case it belongs to super class and I can access that variable in sub class also. How can it be? any valid reasons. My Initial thought was, only I can access super class instance variable and methods in sub class.

Comment: Please, take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9898144/4745608

Comment: @AlexErohin, Understood.Thanks for sharing the above link.

Answer (score 3):

You can access it using the `subclass object.superClassStaticField` or `SuperClassName.superClassStaticField`. Latter is the static way to access a static variable.

For example:

```
public class SuperClassStaticVariable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.a = 2; // works but compiler warning that it should be accessed as static way
        A.a = 2; // ok 
    }
}

class A {   
    static int a;
}
class B extends A {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Static variables are class variables, you can access them using classname.variablename.

```
public class Test {

    public static String a = "";

    Test() {
        a += "testadd";
    }
}

public class Test1 extends Test {

    public Test1() {
        Test.a += "test1add";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test1 test1 = new Test1();
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```